# how to run java lambda function for aws locally and check logs using serverless (sls)

Tags: java, serverless

I know how to answer my question for python and nodejs.

It is simply: `sls invoke local --function functionName` for invocation and `sls logs -f functionName` to view logs. I am confused with java since function is inside class. Any suggestions is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself. I was looking for following:
serverless.yml should contains something like:

```
functions:
  your-lambda-function-name:
    handler: package_name.class_name::lambda_method_name
    ...................................................
    ...................................................
```

then we can invoke:

```
sls invoke -f your-lambda-function-name
```

if we are using any stage like prod or nonprod then

```
sls invoke --stage prod/nonprod -f your-lambda-function-name
```

invoke with logs:

```
sls invoke -f your-lambda-function-name -l
```

only for logs

```
sls logs -f your-lambda-function-name
```

or to monitor live

```
sls logs -f your-lambda-function-name -t
```